# Why does git checkout --ours/theirs not work?

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution

I want to update my template from the source, so I use these commands:

```bash
git remote add template https://github.com/ObsidianPublisher/template-netlify-vercel
git pull template main --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Then I list all the conflict files:

```bash
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U
A
B
C
```

So far so good. I want to keep A. The rest should be overwritten. I use:

```bash
git checkout --ours -- A
git checkout --theirs -- .
```

But checking it again it doesn't work:

```bash
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U
A
B
C
```

Why is that?

Comment: Isn’t that the wrong order if you want to keep `A`? `--theirs .` first, then `--ours A`.

Comment: since `A` is in `.`, I thought using `--theirs .` first will delete the conflict in `A`. It doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git checkout --ours` and `git checkout --theirs` only change the file in the working tree, but do not resolve the conflict. You still have to `git add` the so checked out file to mark the conflict resolved.

Comment: ahh. So git actually have a cache about which file is conflicted, and not actually check whether the conflict markers, right?

Comment: Yes, of course. This "cache" is also called "index" (which was actually called "cache" in early days of Git, as in `git diff --cached`) and is the very same "staging area" where you conduct the changes for the next commit using `git add`.

Comment: wait, they are really the same? That the conflict is also get to the cache as well? Why does it decide to allow conflicts to get to the cache but not allow to commit them?

Comment: As I said, the conflicts are recorded in the index ("cache"). Nevertheless, Git does not allow to commit conflicts, because the inventors of Git thought (and still think) that this is not useful, if not to say meaningless.

Comment: hmm, but if it's not useful to commit conflicts, why is it useful to add them? And can I force commit the conflicts?

Comment: When you `git add` a file with conflicts, then you do not *"add"* the conflict, but you *remove* it. You say: "The content of this file is what the resolution of the conflict looks like and do consider the conflict resolved". If at that time you haven't removed the conflict markers, yet, it's your fault; Git does not care.

Comment: You cannot force to commit an unresolved conflict, because Git will never let you. If you, however, mean if you can leave the conflict markers in the file, then, of course, you can. Just `git add` the file to mark the conflict as resolved. Git does not interpret or mess around with the conflict markers in any way.